# Unable to get listView.ItemClick to be called in MonoDroid

Tags: android, mono, android-listview, xamarin.android

I have the following code:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    progress = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "", "Loading...");
    progress.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);

    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    //Set the Activity's view to our list layout        
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LawsAndRegsList);

    new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
        //Create our adapter
        listAdapter = new LawsAndRegsListAdapter(this);
        this.RunOnUiThread ( () => {
            //Find the listview reference
            listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);

            //Hook up our adapter to our ListView
            listView.Adapter = listAdapter;

            //Wire up the click event
            //listView.ItemClick += new EventHandler<ListView.ItemClickEventArgs>(listView_ItemClick);
            listView.ItemClick += listView_ItemClick;

            listAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged(); 

            progress.Dismiss();
        });
    })).Start();
}

void listView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    //Get our item from the list adapter
    var item = this.listAdapter.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);

    //Make a toast with the item name just to show it was clicked
    Toast.MakeText(this, item.Name + " Clicked!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the ItemClick would not get called?

It looks like what I have read and examples I have seen so what am I doing wrong? thanks for the help.

UPDATE:

Here are the two layouts I have:

LawsAndRegsList:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget28"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/topLevelMenuBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddExpense"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/ButtonHome"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblExpenseCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/LawsAndRegs"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

LawsAndRegsListItem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget28"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/topLevelMenuCellBackground"
    android:layout_height="40px">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#111479"
            android:text="hello"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageItem"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/OrangeAccessoryButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

UPDATE #2:

Added my LIstAdapter code:

public class LawsAndRegsListAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    Activity context;

```
public List<LawsAndRegs> items;

public LawsAndRegsListAdapter (Activity context) //We need a context to inflate our row view from
{
    this.context = context;

    MY_SEB_SERVICE_ContentWS.ContentWS contentWS = new MY_WEB_SERVICE_ContentWS.ContentWS ();
    string sMenu = contentWS.GetMenuXML (146, 1, "", 0, 1033);

    XmlRootAttribute r = new XmlRootAttribute ("Item");
    var ser = new XmlSerializer (typeof(Item), r);
    StringReader stringReader;
    stringReader = new StringReader (sMenu);
    Item obj = (Item)ser.Deserialize (stringReader);
    ItemMenuItem[] m = obj.Menu.Item;
    ItemMenuItem larMenu = null;
    foreach (ItemMenuItem mnu in m)
    {
        if (mnu.ItemID == 155)
        {
            if (this.items == null)
                this.items = new List<LawsAndRegs> ();
            larMenu = mnu;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (larMenu != null)
    {
        foreach (ItemMenuItemMenuItem imimi in larMenu.Menu.Item)
        {
            LawsAndRegs lar = new LawsAndRegs();
            lar.Name = (string)imimi.Items[2];
            lar.Image = (string)imimi.Items[3];
            this.items.Add (lar);
        }
    }
}

public override int Count
{
    get { return items.Count; }
}

public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
{
    return position;
}

public override long GetItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

public LawsAndRegs GetItemAtPosition(int position)
{
    return items[position];
}

public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    //Get our object for this position
    var item = items[position];         

    //Try to reuse convertView if it's not  null, otherwise inflate it from our item layout
    // This gives us some performance gains by not always inflating a new view
    // This will sound familiar to MonoTouch developers with UITableViewCell.DequeueReusableCell()
    var view = (convertView ?? context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.LawsAndRegsListItem, parent, false)) as LinearLayout;

    //Find references to each subview in the list item's view
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.imageItem);
    imgView.Clickable = true;
    TextView textTop = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textTop);
    textTop.Clickable = true;

    var bm = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(
        new Java.Net.URL("http://www.SOME_SITE.com/" + item.Image).OpenStream());
    imgView.SetImageBitmap(bm);

    //Assign this item's values to the various subviews
    textTop.SetText(item.Name, TextView.BufferType.Normal);

    view.Clickable = true;

    //Finally return the view
    return view;
}
```

}

I added the view.clickable code in trying to get this to work.

Comment: What are the items in the list view? Could you show us the code of the layout?

Comment: I updated my post and added the two layouts that make up my list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally!!  I found out my issue... it turned out that the problem was my ImageButton in the ListView.  It was stealing the focus and consuming the touch events.  So in my custom Adapter, in the GetView I needed to do something like the following:

```
var imageButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imageButton1);
imageButton.Focusable = false;
imageButton.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
imageButton.Clickable = true;

imageButton.Click += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("ImageButton {0} clicked", position);
```

That removes the focus from the image button.  The solution was given to me here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/871/how-do-i-get-itemclick-of-a-listview-to-get-called-not-sure-what-have-wrong#latest by Cheesebaron.  Thank you Cheesebaron!!!

I hope this may help another newbie with a similar issue!!

Comment: But your question was "Unable to get listView.ItemClick to be called", not the image button.. Glad to know you have solved your problem though. :D

Comment: Yes, true. ItemClick was not being called because the button was stealing focus and consuming the event.  If I remove the button from the layout or put in the above code the ItemClickmgets called.

Comment: If you want to prevent the image button from over getting focus (and events), you need to add android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to your root LinearLayout of your list item. That will stop the imagebutton from stealing the clicks at all.

Comment: For me, the key was setting those properties in code vs. in the layout file of my listitem row. Setting them in the layout did nothing, but setting them in the code solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in your linear layout of LawsAndRegsListItem, because Android doesn't allow any items to be focusable in listview. Instead of setting every control in your listview to `android:focusable="false"`, the easiest way doing it is setting its root `ViewGroup` to `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`, so it will block every control of it getting focused.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget28"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/topLevelMenuCellBackground"
    android:layout_height="40px"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, don't set the `LinearLayout`'s `Clickable` to `true`. If so, it will gain focused even though its child won't get focused and thus the listview will block any clicking event.

References:

[ListView Tips & Tricks #4: Add several clickable areas](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=525)

[Android Documentation on descendantFocusability](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability)

Comment: Thank you SOOO much for the help.  I will give it a try right now.  However, is there a better way I should be doing a list view?  Seems like a pretty common thing would be to be able to select a cell in a list view, maybe I should be using something else?

Comment: It's hard to say. It depends on the design. In my experience, if listview only contains textviews or images, you could do nothing with descendantFocusability. On the other hand, if your design requires to have something like button, chekcbox, etc. which needs user interactions, I think you just have to deal with it. :)

Comment: The event still does not get called!! I don't get it, I do not see what I have wrong. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It's weird. I tested similar code on my side and it worked fine. How does your adapter look like?

Comment: I will update my post, but one question... do I need to hold the list in the ListActivity?  I create the list in the Adapter, but all the examples I see, create the list ion the activity and pass it to the adapter... should I be doing that?

Comment: You don't need to hold the list in the ListActivity if it's id is "@android:id/list". http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html If your activity is inherited from Activity instead of ListActivity, you probably want to hold it.

Comment: And I think your adapter is fine.

Comment: Yes, if I change my GetView to use the standard view from a sample it works. The one that works is: var view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem2, null); whereas mine is var view = (convertView ?? context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.LawsAndRegsListItem, null)) as LinearLayout;  So I guess something is wrong with my layout.

Comment: Try removing this line of code:"view.Clickable = true"? It works after I remove it.

Comment: hmmm, ok, i will try it, but they were not in there originally

Comment: What do you mean? The code you posted here shows it's in your adapter.

Comment: LOL, yes, i added it earlier in my attempts to get this working.  I will remove them and try it again!

Comment: No, it does not work when I use my custom layout... if I use the standard Android.Resource.Layout.ActivityListItem layout the OnListItemClick gets called.  How do I get that to be called when I use a custom layout?  What am I missing?  Do I need to add a listener?  If so, how?  I have tried that already!!

Answer (score 0):

I also managed to get though this problem by setting the "view.Click" handler inside the adapter::GetView function. Seems to work as well.

```
public class TaskListAdapter : BaseAdapter<Task> {
    Activity context = null;
    IList<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    public TaskListAdapter (Activity context, IList<Task> tasks) : base ()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    [...]

    public override Android.Views.View GetView (int position, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent)
    {


        var view = (convertView ??
            context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(...));
        view.FindViewById<..>(Resource.Id.NameText).SetText ("...", TextView.BufferType.Normal);

        view.Click += (sender, e) => 
        {
            int a=0;
            a++; //breakpoint location is being hit.

        };
        return view;
    }
}
}
```