# ItemClick not bound on Button in MvxGridView

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a problem with binding `Click` event on my item of `MvxGridView` (I'm using `ItemClick` binding).

All is rendering fine and stuff. When I use `TextView` my `GoClick` method is fired properly. But when I change `TextView` to `Button` in my `ItemTemplateView`, then `GoClick` method is not invoked any more.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682082/mvvmcross-changing-viewmodel-within-a-mvxbindablelistview/12685784#12685784) answer (option number 1) all should work fine. But in `Button` case it does not.

Any help appreciated, I'm stuck here.

My viewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private IEnumerable<MyListItem> items;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.items = new List<MyListItem>
        {
            new MyListItem {Name = "Item1"},
            new MyListItem {Name = "Item2"},
        };
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyListItem> Items
    {
        get { return this.items; }
    }

    public ICommand SelectItem
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand<MyListItem>(this.GoClick);}
    }

    public void GoClick(MyListItem item)
    {
        //doSomething
    }
}
```

My layout with `MvxGridView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/black"
    >
       <Mvx.MvxGridView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/itemtemplateview"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items; ItemClick SelectItem"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

My `ItemTemplateView` (which works fine with `TextView`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            local:MvxBind="Text Name"
            />
        <!-- CLICK ON THIS BUTTON DOES NOT WORK -->
        <!--
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            local:MvxBind="Text Name"
            />
        -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is this close to issues like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443364/unable-to-get-listview-itemclick-to-be-called-in-monodroid

Comment: It is similar but I wonder is this really necessary to create custom Adapter for this? I tried to set these properties in itemView.xml with no luck

Comment: I think you are probably just facing an Android issue - search around for Q&As like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703390/listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-working-by-adding-button - if you've tried things, then please do edit the question to provide more information (comments are hard to understand)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the click event of a button, and you're using "Swiss" binding, use:

```
local:MvxBind="Click DoNameClick"/>
```

instead of

```
local:MvxBind="Text Name"
```

Check out the docs: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/databinding

Note - you will have to have a public "DoNameClick" getter in your ViewModel!