# Listview Click Item Click Listener doesnt trigger in xamarin.android

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.android

I'm making an application in Xamarin android where ,I had items in ListView using ArrayAdapter.

While on clicking on item of ListView the trigger doesn't respond to it.
 I have gone through other solutions reference through this site , but didn't work for me.

My code as follows.

Fragment2.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace NavigationDrawerTest
{
    public class Fragment2 : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment 
    {
        private List<string> mItems;
        private ListView mListView;

        public override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
            //SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Fragment2_Layout);

        }

        public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment2_Layout, container, false);
            mListView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myListView);

            mItems = new List<string> ();
            mItems.Add ("One");
            mItems.Add ("Two");
            mItems.Add ("Three");
            mItems.Add ("Four");
            mItems.Add ("Five");

            ArrayAdapter <string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1,objects: mItems.ToArray());
            mListView.Adapter = adapter;
            mListView.ItemClick += mListView_ItemClick;


            return view;
        }
        void mListView_ItemClick(Object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mItems[e.Position]);
        }

    }
}
```

The image as follows where the ListView ItemClickListener doesn't trigger.

[ListView Item Click Listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4aAc.jpg)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14464134/1845593 you might have the same problem

Comment: @user1845593 Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer by slightly in change in code of Fragment2.cs

Code as follows.

```
void mListView_ItemClick(Object Sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
            var item = mItems [e.Position];
            Toast.MakeText(Context, item + " Clicked!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```